# How do i disable hover effect from previous page?

Tags: hover

I have following problem: I have a page with a link, that opens a new page in current window. Below that link I have a new `div` with an explanatory text. Display style of the `div` is set to `style="display: none"`. When I mouse over the link, hover effect changes the style of the `div` to `style="display: block"` and the `div` displays. Then I click on the link and new page opens. Then I go back with the back button of the browser and previous page returns. When I let the mouse on the browser back button the hover effect on the link is still active. Only when I returned to the body of the page, then the effect disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify visited link style to none.
a:visited { display:none } add correct name.